# PowerShell - Invalid cast from System.DateTime to System.ConsoleColor

Tags: powershell

```
# Get Password Expire Date
$EXPDTE = [datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser -Identity $USERNAME -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")

# Subtract Expire Date from Today
$DAYSTOEXP = (($EXPDTE)-(Get-Date)).Days

Write-Host "{0}" -f $EXPDTE
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Write-Host : Cannot bind parameter 'ForegroundColor'. Cannot convert value "1/14/2018 10:39:12 AM" to type 
"System.ConsoleColor". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.ConsoleColor'."
At C:\Users\\Documents\PowerShell\ADPasswordExpire.ps1:14 char:21
+ Write-Host "{0}" -f $EXPDTE
+                     ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand
```

This only happens when using Write-Host and the `-f` operator.

If I do:

**$EXPDTE**

`Sunday, January 14, 2018 10:39:12 AM`

**$EXPDTE.ToString()**

`1/14/2018 10:39:12 AM`

What am I missing here when using `-f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `-f` is short for `-ForeGroundColor`.

Remove `Write-Host`, or use a subexpression:

```
"{0}" -f $EXPDTE
```

---

```
Write-Host $("{0}" -f $EXPDTE)
```

---

**Edit**

With a `[datetime]` object, you should specify the date format. Check out this [ss64 page](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). E.g. use `d` for ShortDatePattern or `D` for LongDatePattern. If you require a different output string, please reply to comment.

```
"Date to Expiry: {0:d}" -f $EXPDTE
"Days to Expire: {0}"-f $DAYSTOEXP
```

Comment: @jes516 what do you want the output string to be?

Comment: Something simple. This is what I just changed it to: `Write-Host $("Date to Expire: {0} nDays to Expire: {1}" -f $EXPDTE, $DAYSTOEXP)`. Is Write-Host necessary? This is in a small script that I run within my text editor (sublime).

Comment: @jes516 What do you literally want the output string to be? `Date to Expire: 1/14/2018 <newline> Days to Expire: 75`?

Comment: Do you really need `Write-Host`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Not at all; my first resolution is to remove `Write-Host`.  Including how to get around for completeness, as it's the source of the error.

Comment: Sorry; I meant to comment on the question rather than your answer (which is correct).

Comment: @gms0ulman only the date. I dont need the exact time the pw expires.

Comment: @jes516 The code already does that. Don't forget the `{0:d}`.